# How to query with a condition "or " on Prismic API?

Tags: laravel, api

I'm using the prismic API, and I'm usin Predicate function to search the API. When we combine several Predicate, it searches with the "AND" clause, while I would like to have "OR". If the API doesn't offer it, how can I search by filter ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Prismic API doesn't support "OR" operations like this.

Some cases can be handled by using the "any" Predicate:
https://prismic.io/docs/laravel/query-the-api/query-predicates-reference#31_0-any

But most of the time you'll need to run multiple queries and handle the logic in your website application.